# Custom layout in code

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create a custom layout, that will have child views though I just can't seem to find the correct way of doing this. The custom layout's purpose is to be a template with some behavior.

Under is what I've tried (among some other stuff).

Code - simplified:

```
public class MyComponent : StackLayout {

    public MyComponentHeader Header { get; set; }

    /* Somewhat feels wrong to add this as a property */
    public class MyComponentHeader : StackLayout {

    }

    /* Somewhat feels wrong to add this as a property */
    public MyComponentBody Body { get; set; }

    public class MyComponentBody : StackLayout {

    }
}
```

Usage - ugh...:

```
<common:MyComponent>
    <common:MyComponent.Header>
        <Label Text="Cool header!"/>
    </common:MyComponent.Header>
    <common:MyComponent.Body>
        <Label Text="Cool body!"/>
    </common:MyComponent.Body>
</common:MyComponent>
```

The reason I want "Header" and "Body" to be separated from a normal StackLayout or other layout in this case is because I want to have control of the items since they are part of the behaviour. I don't want to use something like : give me the children with the x:Name = Header since that is bound to fail.

I hope this is possible :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WPF and it's followup UWP are designed specifically with teh MVVM pattern in mind. While you can use other patterns and even WinForms era approaches, doing so misses about 90% of it's power and runs into totally new issues.

Rather then using Custom Controls (wich has all kinds of issues with DataContext), you should be using what I call "Type targetting Data Templates".

I wrote a intro into MVVM a few years ago. It should get you on the right track: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: That sounds very good and I will definitely read the article. However the idea with this master page is that all real pages which requires a filter, will have some quick filters inside the header as well as an expand button which will display the body with more advanced filters at disposal. It's somewhat like the SlideOverKit (just that I want to try doing something similar myself just to learn). So, in terms of pattern I would say this one would have its own "MVVM/MVC (Filter, FilterPage, FilterController)" and the pages content would be its own, interacting with each other by somthing betwee

Comment: I most certainly need a MVVM lecture, but currently I'm just trying to understand how I can create my own layout tree as explained above :)